# Resolve dependency using NInject in OWIN Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private IAccountService _account;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        this._account.ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

How I could resolve the dependency of IAccountService?? I know that first the NinjectWebCommon.cs is executed and after this class.

Is it possible resolve this passing IAccountService by parameter in a constructor or in the Configuration Method?

Comment: After read a lot of documentation, I've achieved inject the dependency but in another form. I will do a post explaining that for another people that need to do that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bind like that?

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
             RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

               this._account.ConfigureAuth(app);

            app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
            app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);
        }
    }
    public static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<IAccountService>().To<AccountService>();
        return kernel;
    }
```

There is an example using OWIN + Unit that may help you with that:
https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/self-host-webapi-with-owin-and-unity/